# Vectorize Sort by Paritular element of multidimensional array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I've got a multidimensional array of shape (1000000,3,2). Essentially it is 1 million sets of samples, each sample being 3 coordinates (each coordinate has an x and y component). I would like to sort each of the samples by the y component of each coordinate. For example, if vecCoords is the full array andI have one of the samples being vecCoords[0,:,:] = [[1,3],[2,1],[4,2]], I want it sorted to give me [[2,1],[4,2],[1,3]]. I was this vectorized so it is done for each of the 1 million samples. So, the output shape is still (1000000,3,2). I tried doing it iteratively, but my code isn't giving me the correct results there, and it is also slower than I would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a small sample array:

```
In [153]: arr = np.random.randint(0,100,(4,3,2))
In [154]: arr
Out[154]: 
array([[[21, 12],
        [15, 31],
        [17, 88]],

       [[35, 81],
        [99, 58],
        [39, 46]],

       [[54, 54],
        [85, 71],
        [ 9, 19]],

       [[25, 46],
        [62, 61],
        [74, 69]]])
```

The values you want to sort:

```
In [155]: arr[:,:,1]
Out[155]: 
array([[12, 31, 88],
       [81, 58, 46],
       [54, 71, 19],
       [46, 61, 69]])
In [156]: idx=np.argsort(arr[:,:,1], axis=1)
In [157]: idx
Out[157]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [2, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```

Test this sort on one plane:

```
In [159]: arr[1,idx[1],:]
Out[159]: 
array([[39, 46],
       [99, 58],
       [35, 81]])
```

Apply it to all planes:

```
In [161]: arr[np.arange(arr.shape[0])[:,None], idx,:]
Out[161]: 
array([[[21, 12],
        [15, 31],
        [17, 88]],

       [[39, 46],
        [99, 58],
        [35, 81]],

       [[ 9, 19],
        [54, 54],
        [85, 71]],

       [[25, 46],
        [62, 61],
        [74, 69]]])
```

While I had a general idea where I was heading with this, I still had to experiment a bit.

A newish function is supposed to make this easier - though even here I had to try a couple of things:

```
In [168]: np.take_along_axis(arr,idx[:,:,None], axis=1)
Out[168]: 
array([[[21, 12],
        [15, 31],
        [17, 88]],

       [[39, 46],
        [99, 58],
        [35, 81]],

       [[ 9, 19],
        [54, 54],
        [85, 71]],

       [[25, 46],
        [62, 61],
        [74, 69]]])
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for being thorough and explaining each step!